# Replace an Url from Json with a button that gives URL to another function

Tags: json, regex, angular, typescript, pipe

I’m trying to implement a function in my web application, that can discover URLs in a loaded Json via Regular Expressions using angular. Afterwards the URLs get replaced with buttons and when the button gets clicked the exact URL who got replaced gets handed in another function in another component which loads the given URL.

Until now I’m at the point that I can replace the URL of the loaded JSON with a button. I’m using a pipe for that named transform-url.pipe:

```
import {
    Pipe,
    PipeTransform,
    Input,
    Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    DomSanitizer
} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
    name: 'transformUrl',
    pure: false
})

export class TransformUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value: any, ): any {
        if (value.match === 0) {
            return value;
        }
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
            value.replace(/"url:\/\/.*\/.*\/.*"/g, "<button type='button'  >Run</button>")
        );
    }
}
```

Hmtl:

```
<h3>Unrecognized JSON data:</h3>
<pre [innerHTML] = "genericJson | transformUrl"></pre>
```

Sample of Json:

```
"documentVersion": "1.0",
    "documentType": "Urls",
    "name": {
        "request": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "abc": [
                {
                    "productUrl": "url://awrtwtgsfgshsfh/sfg/v1/document/jsfhljhl564356lhgljhsljh5895hj",
                "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attributeSet": {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "426824828246824828282468248": {
                                        "value": "1"
                                    },
                                    "647474373748648248282824": {
                                        "value": "true"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                    "productUrl": "url://adgagjfjfjfjhf/sfg/v1/document/adfah5ahfah5jahlkhaliohßjkjlaß73-3",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attributeSet": {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "426824828246824828282468248": {
                                        "value": "1"
                                    },
                                    "647474373748648248282824": {
                                        "value": "true"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

I found nothing on google on how to do this specific task. Is a pipe even the best solution for this? I tried to implement functions in the pipe but it didnt work. 
Another thing that i cant figure out is how i can make every button unique so the application knows which excat URL it should take when the button is clicked? And how can I select the URL and give it in another function in another component?

Comment: can you post sample `genericJson` data?

Comment: Yes i just added it

Comment: Are all URLs will start with `productUrl` key?

Comment: No they dont...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all rather than using pipe, I have created solution in `Component` only.

1. Stringify JSON which needs to be get values from. `genericJson`
2. Remove first and last `"`, which is matched in regex.
3. Using `*ngFor`, create buttons and pass separate link to `click` function.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8xwder) (check console for button click)

**EDIT:** [NEW DEMO.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fo5p2s)

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  genericJson = { ... some json ... }

  formatedOutput: (string | boolean)[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    // adding formatting to make regex search easier
    const jsonFormattedString = JSON.stringify(this.genericJson, null, 4);
    this.formatedOutput = jsonFormattedString.split('\n');
  }

  onClick(out: string) {
    // do whatever operation on link
    const link = out.match(/url:\/\/.*\/.*\/.*/)[0];
    console.log(link);
  }

  urlFound(out: string): boolean {

    const match = out.match(/"url:\/\/.*\/.*\/.*"/);

    if (match !== undefined && match !== null && match.length > 0) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

**Use matched links in HTML template,**

```html
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let out of formatedOutput">
        <ng-container *ngIf="urlFound(out); else simple_json"><pre>{{out}}<button (click)="onClick(out)">Link</button></pre></ng-container>
        <ng-template #simple_json><pre>{{out}}</pre></ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! This seems to work! Is it possible to show the whole Json on the page and just add the buttons in the Json like you did now?

Comment: This is very strange requirement, but i think this is what you want https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fo5p2s. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should do it like this instead of using pipe:

.html

```
<button (click)="goTo(genericJson.url)">Run</button>
```

.ts

```
genericJson = {
  url: "www.google.com"
};

goTo(url: string) {
  if (url) {
    if (!url.includes("https")) {
      url = "https://" + url;
    }
    window.open(url, "_blank");
  }
}
```